Definition of one-sided continuity
What is the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of one-sided continuity (For instance, left continuity)?
Is it:
a) A function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be left continuous at $x_0 \in D$ if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(x_0-\delta,x_0)\cap D \neq \phi$ and
$x \in (x_0-\delta, x_0)\cap D\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$
OR
b) A function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be left continuous at $x_0 \in D$ if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$x \in (x_0-\delta, x_0]\cap D\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$
(It would be very helpful if you tell me which real analysis book has it as well)

The two definitions are equivalent since if $x=x_0$ the inequality $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$ becomes trivial

@jjagmath well the non-emptiness of the first condition is not really implied by the second one. Like if $D={x_0}$. Not really sure why is it required, I'd say that a function is continuous at every isolated point of its domain, and so left continuous as well...

@ECL An implication of the form "$(A\ne \emptyset$ and $a\in A ) \implies P(a)$" is exactly equivalent from a logic point of view to "$a\in A \implies P(a)$"

@jjagmath Oh sure, I had interpreted it as $A\neq\varnothing$ and $(a\in A\implies P(a))$. Not sure what the statement in the question actually means...

@ECL Ah, good point. I interpreted it the other way.

The two definitions can be distinguished with the following example: Take $f:{1} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ for all $x$. By the second definition, f is left continuous at 1 but we cannot say anything about one sided continuity at 1 by first definition.

Rather we cannot talk about left continuity at 1 by the first definition since the conditions aren't satisfied

By the first definition, and under the interpretation that you evidently share with ECL, no function defined on a domain $[a, b)$ or $[a,b]$ can be left-continuous at $a$, as there exist $\epsilon >0$ (indeed, all of them) for which no such $\delta$ can be found, as $(a-\delta,a)\cap [a,b) =\varnothing$ always. Thus if one chooses this definition and interpretation, $f$ can be continuous at $a$, but not left-continuous. For this reason, I prefer the 2nd definition, where left-continuity is vacuously true in that case.

Okay got it. Understood.
